# Create a Border in a ListView

Tags: android

It's pritty hard to explain what I like to have. In my Layout I got a horizontal LinearLayout.
Now I'd like to know if its possible to create a thin border around it. For example take a look at the ListView, there it also haves those thin borders, I exactly like to have that in my LinearLayout.

I hope you understood me, if you need more information write a comment below.
Thx in advance
safari

Additional Information:
If you take a look at the screenshot you see there those redlines, exactly there i'd like to have those thin borders, like in my Listview up there! Under the screenshot you also find the code of the layout.

[image: What I want]

> 

**Code**

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
 
       <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            



        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


           <FrameLayout
               android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="450dp"
               android:layout_weight="1" />

               <TabWidget
                   android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_alignBottom="@android:id/tabcontent"
                   android:visibility="invisible" />



                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/SmileyContent"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/GoStartseite"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:onClick="onClickGoStartseite"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="0.6" >

                        <TextView
                            style="@style/SmallFont"
                            android:text="@string/gostartseite" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/SmileyOverview"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:onClick="onClickSmileyConfig"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="0.4" >

                        <TextView
                            style="@style/SmallFont"
                            android:text="@string/newfilter"/>

                    </TableRow>

                </LinearLayout>
           
       </RelativeLayout>
      </TabHost>
  
  </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: what kind of thin border exactly you are talking about? Attach sample snap if possible

Comment: can you please add some screen shots or code...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood from your question is that it actually might require setting the background of your layout.

This can be done by creating your own border.xml. [Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/FXdAtjmVnEc) is somewhat similar question answering what you need.

Answer (score 0):

if all you need is to create a border then take a parentView , set background by border color ,set pading by border thikness , then add child inside with foreground as its background .